# Trigger same CSS animation on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to trigger a CSS animation onclick, but have it restart after each click. I know I can toggle the animation on and off, but I'd like to just trigger the animation every time the button is clicked. Also, initially the CSS animation should not run. Only run when clicked.

Here's my pen.
http://codepen.io/omarel/pen/JRwpZp

**HTML :**

```
<a href="#" class="addtocart">click me</a>
```

**Jquery :**

```
 $('.addtocart').click(function () {  
     $(this).addClass('on');
 });
```

**CSS :**

```
.addtocart {
    position: relative;
}

    .addtocart.on {
        -webkit-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
        -moz-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
        -ms-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
        -o-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
        animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    }

@keyframes cartbtnFade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    10% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    15% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    30% {
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    40% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can listen to when the animation ends, then remove the class 'on'

```
var animationEvent = 'webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend';
$('.addtocart').click(function () { 
  $(this).addClass('on');
  $(this).one(animationEvent, function(event) {
    $(this).removeClass('on')
  });
});
```

```js
$('.addtocart').click(function () { 
  $(this).addClass('on');
  $(this).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(event) {
    $(this).removeClass('on')
  });
});
```

```css
.addtocart {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
 }
 .addtocart.on {
    -webkit-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    -moz-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    -ms-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    -o-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
 }

@keyframes cartbtnFade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:translateY(-100%);
  }
  10% {
   transform:translateY(-100%);

  }
  15% {
   transform:translateY(0);
 }
 30% {
   transform:translateY(-50%);
   
 }
 40% {
    transform:translateY(0%);

 }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="addtocart">click me</a>
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I noticed, I'm looking into it right now

Comment: @DaniP Nice. Works perfectly. Though I don't understand why having it outside stops after 3 clicks. odd

Comment: **.one** just bind the function once for each event then it ".off" that event from the element in this case I guess you can make two clicks because for example on chrome can identify both `webkitAnimationEnd and animationend`

Comment: That makes sense. In that case, either nest it within the function provided, or use $(query).on instead of .one, right?

Comment: @DaniP wow nice. Post this because that seems to be the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an on click event, use :focus.

```
.addtocart:focus {
    -webkit-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    -moz-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    -ms-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    -o-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
    animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
}
```

Now, whenever an element with the .addtocart class is focused (or clicked on), it will have those styles. When you click away, the styles will go away.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.delay()` and `.queue()/dequeue()` if you want to add/remove class :

```
$('.addtocart').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('on').delay(500).queue(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').dequeue(); 
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.addtocart').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('on').delay(500).queue(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').dequeue(); 
  });
});
```

```css
.addtocart {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.addtocart.on {
  -webkit-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
  -moz-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
  -ms-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
  -o-animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
  animation: cartbtnFade 0.6s 0.1s 1 linear alternate;
}

@keyframes cartbtnFade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:translateY(-100%);
  }
  10% {
    transform:translateY(-100%);

  }
  15% {
    transform:translateY(0);
  }
  30% {
    transform:translateY(-50%);

  }
  40% {
    transform:translateY(0%);

  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="addtocart">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove the css class on every click and inorder for you to run the css only while clicking, do this onload not on ready

Example 
.addClass and .removeClass

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to remove your `on` class every second:

```
var $post = $(".addtocart");

setInterval(function() {
    $post.removeClass("on");
}, 1000);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRZykG

Answer (score 0):

As Jacob said there is no need for javascript.
You can use CSS `:focus` or `:target` as in this codepen https://codepen.io/sebilasse/pen/rrOYQj?editors=1100

-
    
    .root {
      appearance: none;
      position: relative;
      width: 120px;
      height: 50px;
      transition: all .1s linear;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

```
.animation {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0%   { opacity: 0; box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red; }
    40%  { opacity: 0.8; }
    80%  { box-shadow: 0 0 0 80px red; }
    99% { opacity: 0; box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px red; }
}

.root:hover ._focus:focus::after,
.root:target ._target::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 20px;
    top: 25px;
    transform: perspective(1px) translate(-50%, -50%);

  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

```
<h3>crossbrowser animation onClick hacks</h3>
<button class="root">
  <div class="animation _focus" tabindex="0" onanimationend="this.blur()">    
</div>
  contra: steals focus
</button>
<button id="btn_1" class="root">
  <a class="animation _target" href="#btn_1"></a>
  contra: needs id
</button>
```